How to use C caller block in Simulink
I'm trying to add a C caller block in Simulink so I can add my own C functions to a Simulink Model. I have referred to a built in example in Matlab which, called 'CallCFunctionsUsingCCallerBlockExample'.
This contains 3 folders, called 'include', 'slprj' and 'src'as well as some files, such as the slx file which defines the model.
The main problems I have are

when attempting to specify Include directories in the Simulate Target section of Model Properties,  I am not sure how to make the Include folder. Presumably it's not just going to be the same one as in their example, or is it? If not, how do I know which files to put in this folder and what they need to have in? This doesn't seem to be explained in the Matlab Help section on using C caller blocks.

knowing which folders to have in my Matlab model directory. Do I need to include the slprj and src files, together with their contents and do these need to be the same as in their example? If not, how do I know what to put in them?

additionally, their C file which defines the C functions used in the model (myfunc.c) refers to 2 files at the start with the lines #myfunc.h and #tmwtypes.h. Whilst I can see where myfunc.h is in the directory and I understand what it does, which is to declare the C functions defined in myfunc.c, I can't see where tmwtypes.h is. Do I need it and again, if so, is it going to be the same as for their example and if not, how can I find out what needs to be in it?


